# activate git annotate in pycharm under VCS

Tags: pycharm

By mistake I deleted .idea and .git files, and after that the Git option under `VCS` on pycharm menu disappeared.

Earlier I could go to PyCharm>VCS>Git>Annotate

But now the option altogether disappeared. 
Please help.

Comment: I can do all git stuff separately from my terminal. so git itself is not the issue. I want to re enable git annoate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important:** you should make a backup of your entire project directory before trying the stuff below, just in case things don't go as expected.

First you'd need to restore the `.git` directory (if you didn't do it already), without it PyCharm doesn't know your project is using git as VCS, a likely reason for the missing menu.

If previously you saved your project's setting `.idea` dir in git (and you still have another clone of your git repo) or in the Settings Repository (see [Synchronizing and Sharing Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/synchronizing-and-sharing-settings.html)) you could try to restore it from there.

Another possibility would be to re-create the project from the existing directory, see [Importing Project from Existing Source Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/importing-project-from-existing-source-code.html):

> You can set up a project around the existing source code created
>   externally, in other words, in another IDE or in a dedicated editor.
>   PyCharm analyzes the code base, adds the `.idea` directory with
>   settings, and marks the project with the special icon project icon.

Some default project configs would be produced, so you may need to restore your non-default settings manually. Or, if you have some other project with same/similar settings you can try to export (some of) them from that project and import them in the newly created project, see [Exporting and Importing Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/exporting-and-importing-settings.html).